# Can't increment a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to create a folder for each line in my txt file, for example "[023] Text in the 23th line of the file".

I am using the code below, but it says that the syntax is incorrect. By splitting it into parts and using comments I was able to see that the `if` is also a problem but I couldn't solve it.

```
@echo off
chcp 1252>nul
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
set Nbres=0
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ fnID_fr.txt"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"

    if %Nbres% leq 10 
    goto :set10
    if %Nbres% leq 100
    goto :set100
    goto :set0

:set100
    set DIGITS=0
    goto :set0
:set10
    set DIGITS=00
:set0

    if not exist "!Nbres! !var!" mkdir "!Nbres! !var!"

    set Nbres=%Nbres%+1

)
chcp %cp%>nul
pause
```

Here is an example of what I would like to have... I would like to have only the title instead of having to writte every number at every line...

[image][image]

Comment: there seems to be a ton of unnecessary stuff in your batch file at the moment. i'm a little unclear on what is actually written on the lines in your text file - can you copy some examples into your question? or is it that you would like to make whatever text is on the 23rd line the title of your folder but start it with a [23]? or do you just want the text?

Comment: I have added more informations below de code. Is it more clear ?

Comment: You simply ***can not*** use labels inside a (code block)

Comment: yes Wyz that screenshot clarified; I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a folder in a directory for each line in a text file, all you need is this:

```
@echo off

set "txt=C:\Your\Text\File.txt"
set "dir=C:\Directory\Where\You\Want\Your\Folders\Made"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in (%txt%) do (
    set /A count+=1
    set "long=00!count!"
    set "new=[!long:~-3!]"
    if not exist "%dir%\!new! %%A" md "%dir%\!new! %%A"
)

pause
```

You don't absolutely have to have variables but I find it makes writing this kind of stuff easier. `for` will loop through your text file and assign the line's text to parameter `%%A` and add a number to the `count` variable. It sets a variable called `long` as `count` with two zeros in front of it to fit your naming scheme (you can add more zeroes if you get above 999 lines in your text file), then it sets a variable called `new` as the last three characters of `long` (hence the `!long:~-3!`). Finally, it checks to see if there's already a folder for your line, and if it doesn't exist it makes that folder with `%dir%\!new! %%A`. Holler at me if you have any questions; there may have been a quicker way to get there than I've proposed but this allows you to change a couple things on the trip there.

Comment: Obviously the text contains spaces, without `"delims="` you'll catch only the 1st space seperated word.

Comment: good catch - I was getting hasty copy/pasting stuff back and for from my test batch as I was editing my answer from his original question.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `!txt!` and `!dir!` rather than `%txt%` and `%dir%` when delayed expansion is enabled. And note that folder names containing `!` and `^` might be problematic due to delayed expansion...

Comment: what would be the point of using `!txt!` and `!dir!` if the values of `%txt%` and `%dir%` never change from what they are initially set to? just personal preference to make things the look relatively the same during delayed expansion? or an actual reason?